# Setting a default data validation value in Google Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, checkbox, default-value

I am working on a materials order spreadsheet in Google sheets that has four main columns and a pertinent cell. Column D contains a list for a default order amount, column E contains a list of amounts for "this order", column F contains a list of amounts to add to the order from existing stock, column G contains a checkbox to indicate if the default order has been adjusted in any way, and the pertinent cell (H4) contains a number that scales the default order.

The "This Order" column (E) is computed by multiplying the default order (column D) by the value in H4 then subtracting the value in the same row from column F. I have written a loop to check if the value in the "This Order" column has been altered (either manually in the cell or through the existing stock column) and if it has, to insert a new checkbox into column G. What I cannot figure out, however, is if there is a way to insert this checkbox pre-checked rather than as an empty checkbox.

Here's the code if that is helpful:

```
function onChange(){
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let thisOrder = ws.getRange('E13:E83').getValues();
  let standardOrder = ws.getRange('D13:D83').getValues();
  let houseNumber = ws.getRange('H4').getValue();

  for (let i = 0; i < thisOrder.length; i++){
    if(thisOrder[i] != standardOrder[i]*houseNumber) {
      ws.getRange(i+13, 7).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can set it's value to the the checkedvalue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sh.getRange(1, 1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build())
sh.getRange(1, 1).setValue("TRUE");
```

Comment: So the result when I use setValue is that it removes the checkbox and fills the cell with TRUE.

Comment: In my sheet it created a checkbox in A1 and checked it

Comment: I figured out what was happening. The previous sheet creator had set up the data validation with custom values that was causing the issue. I replicated the sheet from scratch so that the checkboxes had standard data validation and it worked. Thanks.